# How can I fire event for system variables?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am trying to make event that fire when `Application.OpenForms.Count` changed?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a pre-built listener but I would suspect you could just run an Async threaded while loop checking and when the number changes return the Async results and have an event fire from that

Comment: It's the sort of problem that [Rx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx) was created to solve.

Comment: Can you please set the appropriate tags on this question? And can you please read [ask]?

Comment: @StevenByrne thanks, but I'm looking for better way.

Comment: @PouriaSharif I would suggest Rx as noted by Paul Hicks in that case. Good luck!

Comment: thanks @StevenByrne, let me check Rx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do this very simply with Rx. First, NuGet "System.Reactive.Windows.Forms", and then you can do this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100.0))
        .Select(n => Application.OpenForms.Count)
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Subscribe(count =>
        {
            /* Changed so do something here */
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        });
```

This is obviously a polling-based solution so you need to choose an appropriate `TimeSpan` for your needs.

To stop the subscription, when closing down your application, you just call `subscription.Dispose();`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily hook into that. What would be better is to create your own subclass of `Form` and use that as your base. Increment and decrement your own counter with events that applies to your use case.

Comment: thanks, The problem is I need this for a project that contains 1000 forms, and I don't have access to change all classes.

Comment: @PouriaSharif perhaps you should explain in your question what you are hoping to accomplish.